# Is it possible to read a file line-by-line in while also skipping a given number of lines Python

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, iteration

I am trying to write a program in python that parses out lines of data that match certain criteria from an input file to a series of output files.

This program reads an input file containing the start and stop positions of genes on a chromosome. For each line of this input file, it opens a second input file line-by-line that contains the locations of known SNPs on the chromosome of interest. If the SNP is located between the start and stop position of the gene being iterated, it is copied to a new file.

The problem with my program as it stands is that it is inefficient. For each gene being analyzed, the program starts reading the input file of SNP data from the very first line and does not stop until it reaches a SNP that is located on a chromosomal position that is greater (i.e. has a higher position number) than the stop position of the gene being iterated. As all the gene and SNP data is ordered by chromosomal location, the speed and efficiency of my program would be greatly improved if, for each gene being iterated, I could somehow ‘tell’ my program to start reading the input file of SNP location data from the last line that was read in the last iteration; rather than from the first line of the file.

Is there any way to do this Python? Or do all files have to be read from the first line?

My code so far is below. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
import fileinput
import shlex
geneCoordinates = open("Gene Coordinates.txt",'r')
geneCoordinates = list(geneCoordinates)
n = (len(geneCoordinates))
nSNPsPerGene=open("C:/Users/gwilymh/Desktop/Python/SNPsPerGene/nSNPs per gene.txt", 'a')

i=0
for i in range(i,n):
    x=i
    L=shlex.shlex(geneCoordinates[x],posix=True)
    L.whitespace += ','
    L.whitespace_split = True
    L=list(L)
    output=open((("C:/Users/gwilymh/Desktop/Python/SNPsPerGene/%s.txt")%(str(L[2]))), 'a')
    geneStart=int(L[2])
    geneStop=int(L[3])
    for line in fileinput.input("SNPs.txt"):
        if not fileinput.isfirstline():
            nSNPs=0
            SNP=shlex.shlex(line,posix=True)
            SNP.whitespace += '\t'
            SNP.whitespace_split = True
            SNP=list(SNP)
            SNPlocation=int(SNP[0])
            if SNPlocation < geneStart:
                continue
            if SNPlocation >= geneStart:
                if SNPlocation <= geneStop:
                    nSNPs=nSNPs+1
                    output.write(str(SNP))
                    output.write("\n")
            else: break
    nSNPsPerGene.write(("%s\t%s")%s(str(L[2]),nSNPs))
```

Comment: It's hard to visualise the data with samples of each. Are they glorified CSV files (ie. line orientated) if so consider using something like SQLite as it's builtin to Python and would make your task a lot easier. You'd have all the benefits of SQL without having to worry about file positions. Also you'd be able to generate ad-hoc against your data. I've made a massive presumption on your data.

Comment: Are you looking for `file.seek()`?

Comment: Using a SQL database may be the best option, as the input data is in a csv file and a tab delimited file. Alternatively, is there a way in Python to somehow 'save' the line position in the second for loop, so that the first for loop does not have to iterate over lines in the file SNPs.txt again and again?

Answer (score 1):

just use an iterator (at a scope outside of the loop) to keep track of your position in the second file. It should look something like this:

```
import shlex
geneCoordinates = open("Gene Coordinates.txt",'r')
geneCoordinates = list(geneCoordinates)
n = (len(geneCoordinates))
nSNPsPerGene=open("C:/Users/gwilymh/Desktop/Python/SNPsPerGene/nSNPs per gene.txt", 'a')

i=0

#NEW CODE - 2 lines added.  By opening a file iterator outside of the loop, we can remember our position in it
SNP_file = open("SNPs.txt")
SNP_file.readline() #chomp up the first line, so we don't have to constantly check we're not at the beginning
#end new code.


for i in range(i,n):

   x=i
   L=shlex.shlex(geneCoordinates[x],posix=True)
   L.whitespace += ','
   L.whitespace_split = True
   L=list(L)
   output=open((("C:/Users/gwilymh/Desktop/Python/SNPsPerGene/%s.txt")%(str(L[2]))), 'a')
   geneStart=int(L[2])
   geneStop=int(L[3])

   #NEW CODE - deleted 2 lines, added 4
   #loop until break
   While 1:
      line = SNP_file.readLine()
      if not line: #exit loop if end of file reached
         break
      #end new code - the rest of your loop should behave normally

      nSNPs=0
      SNP=shlex.shlex(line,posix=True)
      SNP.whitespace += '\t'
      SNP.whitespace_split = True
      SNP=list(SNP)
      SNPlocation=int(SNP[0])
      if SNPlocation < geneStart:
          continue
      #NEW CODE - 1 line changed
      else: #if SNPlocation >= geneStart: 
      #logic dictates that if SNPLocation is not < geneStart, then it MUST be >= genestart. so ELSE is sufficient
          if SNPlocation <= geneStop:
              nSNPs=nSNPs+1
              output.write(str(SNP))
              output.write("\n")
              #NEW CODE 1 line added- need to exit this loop once we have found a match.
              #NOTE - your old code would return the LAST match. new code returns the FIRST match.
              #assuming there is only 1 match this won't matter... but I'm not sure if that assumption is true.
              break
      #NEW CODE - 1 line deleted
      #else: break else nolonger required. there are only two possible options.

      j = j+1
   nSNPsPerGene.write(("%s\t%s")%s(str(L[2]),nSNPs))
```